# spring 3 , tiles can not display image or use css style

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, tiles

I have deleloped a simple spring 3 application following a tutorial. After that, I did integrated tiles 2. Right now I am trying to use css style in my tiles but i can not do this and i can not even display an image.

Inside my tiles.xml I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="base.definition"
    template="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/menu.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="styles" value="base.css"/>
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/footer.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="dogBreed" extends="base.definition">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Contact Manager" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/dogBreed.jsp" />
</definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

Inside layout.jsp I have

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/styles/style.css"/>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title" ignore="true" /></title>
</head>
<body>

<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%;height:100%">
    <tr>
        <td height=10% width=100%><tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height=80% width=20%><tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" /></td>
        <td width=80%  height=80%><tiles:insertAttribute name="body" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height=10% width=100%><tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want is to remove the table structure and use css. For this I use on layout.jsp the following:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/style style.css"/>
```

Now inside my header.jsp I have:

```
<div id="header">

   <div class="top_right">

        <div class="languages">
            <div class="lang_text">Languages:</div>
            <a href="#" class="lang"><img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/styles/images/en.gif" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a>
            <a href="#" class="lang"><img src="styles/images/de.gif" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a>       
        </div>

        <div class="big_banner">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/banner728.jpg" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a>
        </div>

    </div>


    <div id="logo">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" title="" border="0" width="182" height="85" /></a>
    </div>
   </div>
```

None of the imaeges are getting displayed here and i do not understand why.

The folder styles which cotnrains css and images is in the rood folder of the war.

Also I get an error in my console saying that "no mapping found for HTTP request with uri /pedsample/styles/images/en.gif in dispatcher servlet with name spring"

My web.xml contains the following if od any help:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot,
giannis

Comment: Can you download the images and css (by hand)?

Answer (score 1):

It's not related to Tiles.

Since `DispatcherServlet` is configured to handle all URL in your application, you need to configure it to handle requests for static content.

Since Spring 3.0.4 it can be done by adding `<mvc:resources>` to your Spring config (`<mvc:annotation-driven />` is also needed):

```
<mvc:resources location="/styles/" mapping="/styles/**" />
```

**See also:**

- [15.12.4 mvc:resources](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources)

Comment: @user529065: http://blog.springsource.com/2010/07/22/spring-mvc-3-showcase/. Also see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-annotation-driven for example of changes you need to do in the head of your XML file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that your main problem is that the server is not able to provide your static content (images, css):

> Also I get an error in my console saying that "no mapping found for HTTP request with uri /pedsample/styles/images/en.gif in dispatcher servlet with name spring"

What you need is a configured mapping for your static content in the spring configuration:

```
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for by efficiently serving up static resources -->
<mvc:resources location="/styles/" mapping="/styles/**"/>
<mvc:resources location="/images/" mapping="/images/**"/>
```

For more details: look at chapter ["15.12.4 mvc:resources" of the spring reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

**Added**
Of course you need to declare the mvc prefix:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
```

Comment: thanks a lot both of you. I will look at it in more detail and update here as well.

Comment: ok guys. I have now the following problem: When i try to deploy the application I get the following error:
313  [http-8080-1] ERROR org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 21 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml] is
ed exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "mvc" for element "mvc:resources" is not bound.
Inside my spring-servlet.mxl I have:
  <mvc:resource mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

thanks again guyes

Comment: @user529065: see my extended answer

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using **spring 3.0.4** or later otherwise the tag `mvc:resources` will not work, as it was introduced with that version according to the book "Spring in Action" book.