# CSS Style ignored when inserted page in Spring Tiles

Tags: css, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, tiles2

I'm developing a web app using Spring MVC 4. I generated the base of the app with Spring Roo. Right now I'm working in the front end with Spring Tiles 2.2.2. I downloaded a responsive template and split the code to fit each part of the template.

The problem is when I try to load the index, the css style is ignored or something like that.

This is the original template

[image: Original Template]

And this is how it looks with Spring

[image: My awful template]

Notice how the base of the template (header and menu) are identical, only the dynamic page has problems.

Here is my code:

**WEB-INF/tiles/tiles-definitions.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>

    <definition name="defaultTemplate" template="/WEB-INF/template/default/template.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/template/default/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/template/default/menu.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/index.jspx" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/template/default/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

**WEB-INF/views/views.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN"
    "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>

  <definition name="index" extends="defaultTemplate">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/index.jspx" />
  </definition>

  <definition name="dataAccessFailure" extends="defaultTemplate">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/dataAccessFailure.jspx" />
  </definition>

  <definition name="resourceNotFound" extends="defaultTemplate">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/resourceNotFound.jspx" />
  </definition>

  <definition name="uncaughtException" extends="defaultTemplate">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/uncaughtException.jspx" />
  </definition>

  <definition name="home" extends="defaultTemplate">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/home.jspx" />
  </definition>  
</tiles-definitions>
```

**WEB-INF/template/default/template.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>AdminLTE | Dashboard</title>
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>
<!-- bootstrap 3.0.2 -->
<link href="/sirc/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- font Awesome -->
<link href="/sirc/resources/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- Ionicons -->
<link href="/sirc/resources/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- Theme style -->
<link href="/sirc/resources/css/AdminLTE.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
</head>
<body class="skin-blue">
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
    <div class="wrapper row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" />
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery 2.0.2 -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="/sirc/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE App -->
    <script src="/sirc/resources/js/AdminLTE/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
    <script src="/sirc/resources/js/AdminLTE/demo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml**

```
<aside class="right-side">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
        <h1>
            Dashboard <small>Control panel</small>
        </h1>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
            <li class="active">Dashboard</li>
        </ol>
    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">

        <!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                <!-- small box -->
                <div class="small-box bg-aqua">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <h3>150</h3>
                        <p>New Orders</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="icon">
                        <i class="ion ion-bag"></i>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="small-box-footer"> More info <i
                        class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
      ...
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
</aside>
```

What I've tried is to put these annotations in the index.jsp

```
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8" session="false" autoFlush="true"  />

<jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" doctype-root-element="html"
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" />
```

Also I tried this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006663/spring-3-tiles-can-not-display-image-or-use-css-style) with no luck

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE 1**

Following @Tung Vo suggestions I checked the css and js url and I found that I was omitting some files. Also I don't know why the `<textarea> </textarea>` tag was stopping the correct rendering so I fixed adding some text like this  some text . With these adjustments my page looks now like this:

[image: Update]

But I can't make those icons stay hidden or to obey the css

**UPDATE 2 - Probable Solution (Testing phase)**

I was testing the order of the html elements and I found a problem with this code

```
<li>
   <a href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> 
      Home
    </a>
</li>
```

I changed the order of the tags and the code is like this

```
<li>
   <i class="fa fa-dashboard"> 
      <a href="#"> Home</a>
   </i>
</li>
```

Now the **Home** icon is displayed correctly, I guess the solution is to change the icons order and only then the CSS is being taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved adding spaces to the icons and wherever is needed. I suppose that Spring was removing the natural spaces from the template icon tags in the render phase. Examples:

```
<div class="icon">
    <i class="ion ion-pie-graph">&#160;</i>
</div>
<a href="#" class="small-box-footer">
    More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right">&#160;</i>
</a>
```

Also note that the space is defined `&#160;` because `&nbsp;` doesn't work (or least didn't work for me) in Spring Tiles.

**Note:** I'm using files with JSPX extension, JSP files doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but it's possible that it's fixed when you change

```
<div class="icon">
  <i class="ion ion-bag"></i>
</div>
```

into

```
<div>
   <i class="icon ion ion-bag"></i>
</div>
```

I've just checked [Ionic Icons](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#icons) (just because too many icons are displayed at the same time on your page) and maybe it's just a minor markup issue.
As found at the ionic icon examples, maybe it's only e.g. `<i class="icon ion-bag"></i>`, but just give both a try.

Comment: When I change what you suggest, the icons are bigger and appear in the front. Thanks

Comment: Glad that helped somehow; does it look ok now or do you still have css issues?

Comment: It still have css issues, when I say icons are bigger, I tried to say that looks worse :(. I'm thinking it's something about configuration in the moment when the page is injected to the template or something like that

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I'd think is has to do with the css, just looking at the suggested markup at the ionic page; you could inspect the page with some web dev tool (firebug or else) to check which css applies to the div / i - tag where the icon is displayed and compare it with the original template. There has to be some css that provides that only 1 icon is displayed at one tag instead of these multiple icons.

Answer (score 1):

```
try

<!-- bootstrap 3.0.2 -->
<link href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/sirc/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- font Awesome -->
<link href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/sirc/resources/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- Ionicons -->
<link href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/sirc/resources/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- Theme style -->
<link href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/sirc/resources/css/AdminLTE.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: I applied this change with no luck, but I check all the URL's and I found that I was making some mistakes, so I correct them. I updated my question with an image of the current page.